# Dropzone.js call a custom function after file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to call my own function after the file/files successfully uploaded. This is what I have done so far. Files are being uploaded without a problem but the following code is not working actually.

I just put this code above the Dropzone upload form..

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
          maxFilesize: 10, // Mb
          init: function () {
              this.on('completemultiple', function () {
                 alert("sdfsdf");
              });
          }
       };
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "uploadMultiple: true" to your init.

```
$(function() {
       Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
          maxFilesize: 10, // Mb
          uploadMultiple : true,
          init: function () {
              this.on('completemultiple', function () {
                 alert("sdfsdf");
              });
          }
       };
   });
```

Comment: @TharinduLucky Try using this. `$(".drop-zone").dropzone({
  url : url,
        maxFilesize: 10, // Mb
  uploadMultiple : true,
  init : function() {
   this.on('completemultiple', function() {
    alert("sdfsdf");
   });
  }
 });`

Comment: what to put in `url` variable ? And what's the class `.drop-zone` ?

Comment: `.drop-zone` is the class to mark element you want to attach Dropzone to, usually a form. url is the action url of the form. I created Dropzone programmatically [link](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically)

Comment: Oh no it's WORKING!!! :) My bad, actually I had linked dropzone.js on the footer. I moved it to the header. Now your code works!! :) However, the code in your ANSWER (not the comment)  still not working. Why is that ?